Cannot convert type 'System.Nullable<double>[]' to 'double[]?' via a built-in conversion
var response = await _controller.SendEmbeddingRequest(request);
var resModel = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<EmbeddingResponse>(response);    
if (resModel != null && resModel.data.Count() > 0)
{
    var embedding = resModel.data[0].embedding;
    return embedding as double[];
}

Последняя строка выдаёт ошибку:
Cannot convert type 'System.Nullable<double>[]' to 'double[]?' via a built-in conversion.

Как вернуть Task<double[]>?

System.Nullable<double>[] это то же самое что double?[]. Это значит, что массив состоит из чисел либо null. Каким образом вам нужно его преобразовать в массив чисел, которые не допускают null - не знаю. Возможно вам нужен .Select(x => x ?? 0) либо .Where(x => x.HasValue).Select(x => x.Value), либо .Cast<double>(), всё зависит от того как вы хотите обрабатывать null
